# How do I live stream a queue of videos from ffmpeg to my site then embed it to a page?

Tags: linux, html, video, ffmpeg

I have a queue of videos I want to stream using ffmpeg to my site and then embed it onto the homepage. I think I have the embed part down,(video tag then source it to the url ffmpeg is streaming to?) but I have no idea how I create a queue of videos for ffmpeg and then stream it to my site. Should I make a bash script that when ffmpeg is done streaming one video it moves onto the next or is there a built in function to ffmpeg that has a queue?

Comment: why are you using ffmpeg to stream the videos? are they on-demand videos that you're just trying to serve or do you want to create a 'fake' live stream. If you know the videos in advance then ffmpeg can take a list rather than a single video as input. If your goal is a create a live TV-channel-like live stream then it's probably not the best way to go

Comment: I guess its "TV-like", I have a folder of videos that I want to live stream (as in, when everyone goes to the page they see the video at the same time) but only one channel. Think I found a nginx module to do it called RTMP or something but I have no idea how to work it.